# Why won't VS 2010 ATL Simple Object wizard generate .cpp/.h files when project name has hyphen?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, atl, wizard

This is both a question and a "heads-up" for Visual Studio project naming.

I'm building an ATL/COM project in VS 2010, and when I ran the **Add --> Class --> ATL Simple Object** wizard to create class Foo, only the Foo.rgs file was created, and the expected Foo.cpp and Foo.h files didn't show up.

After several variations of trying to make the wizard work (with different options checked and so on), I still had no success.  There was no error message, no indication that something had failed beyond "no source files" in the output.

In the course of trying to find an answer to "why is that," I ran across a mention that the ProgID field needed to be manually filled in with ProjectName.ClassName for the project and class in question.  When I tried to enter the project name (Some-Project), the wizard complained that the hyphen was an "illegal character" in that field.

Web searches and variations on "why won't ATL wizard generate files" searches here also came up empty.

So, guessing that "no dashes allowed" in the ProgID field might have further implications, I set about changing all the dashes in my project name, file names, directory names, and so on to underscores to see what effect that would have. "Some-Project" became "Some_Project" and "Random-Module.*" become "Random_Module.*" throughout the project.

With all the dashes/hyphens converted to underscores, the wizard ran correctly, and all the expected files magically appeared with all the required COM/ATL plumbing stuff included.

So . . .

1) Any idea why it's "legal" to have a project with dashes in the name, but the dashes break the wizard?

2) Whatever the reason, I recommend not using dashes/hyphens in Visual Studio project names.

Comment: Have you prodded Microsoft about this issue on Microsoft Connect?

Comment: Not yet.  I imagine that conversation is somewhere in my future.

Comment: So, you wanted to enter a value with a dash in ProjectName.ClassName. How do you expect to see it in your code? Can you create a C++ class with a dash? As you see, the wizard will use the value in the C++ code. They just decided to simplify things. They provided a single field for the project, that later will be used in the code. If they needed to support all this unusual setups, the wizard would contain a lot of useless fields. If you really want dashes, create an empty project and do everything by hand. The wizard is provided to simplify your workflow.

Comment: I'm not "married" to the idea of dashes in project names.  I got used to using dashes in a non-MS environment.  When I created the project, I used a hyphenated name out of habit, not knowing that this would break a wizard later on.  I found it curious that VS permits a dash/hyphen in a project name, but that dash will break the ATL wizard when the wizard attempts to generate source files.  No plans to "force" dashes in projects.  New habit = underscore.

Comment: The wizard is driven by a script that parses project files and apparently does not do it right with that unexpected hyphen. It looks like a side glitch, and because the wizard is just a helper you can always add stuff manually without it. I would suggest posting this onto http://connect.microsoft.com/ so that maybe someone at MS checks this out.

Answer (score 1):

Because the wizard uses c and c++ preprocessing directives (macros) that will contain your project's name to generate new files and code in them and to generate code in already existing files, and because these preprocessing directives cannot understand correctly hyphen in their names. See the standard about c/c++ macros for this, but remember for instance all macros you have already seen : there are a lots of underscore "_" to separate names, but no hyphen.